# How to set up timer in JavaScript by passing a parameter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, settimeout, arrow-functions

I'm trying to set up the timeout using the HTML input box, and use this as a parameter to `setTimeout`.

It's a very simple task, but I'm not an JS developer, so I'm not sure on how to pass the parameter properly to the arrow function.

HTML code consists only of 2 elements.

```
<button id="myElementId">Click me</button>
<input id="milliseconds" type="number" placeholder="number of milliseconds"/>
```

And my JS code looks like:

```
const clickbutton = document.getElementById('myElementId');
const millis = parseInt(document.getElementById('milliseconds').value, 10);

clickbutton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    setTimeout(() => { alert("I work");
  }, millis); // <-- here I don't want to use a static value 
});
```

However it seems like I can't get the value of `millis` from outer scope inside the arrow function.

I also tried with passing the second argument:

```
const clickbutton = document.getElementById('myElementId');
const millis = parseInt(document.getElementById('milliseconds').value, 10);

clickbutton.addEventListener('click', (event, millis) => {
    setTimeout(() => { alert("I work");
  }, millis); 
});
```

with no luck there.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: put the `const millis = ...` line inside the timout function, else it wont pick up the value, instead `millis` will just be null on load

Comment: Your assignment to `millis` will not extend into the future. With your code, `millis` will remain at whatever value it gets set to *at the time the line of code runs*, even if you hadn't mistakenly used `const` for a value that's supposed to change. One way to fix this is to turn it into a function: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/m1xqL8ys/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the value in the click event listener because otherwise it's not defined (it's only defined after you type something in the input and decide to click the button):

```js
const clickbutton = document.getElementById('myElementId');

clickbutton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const millis = parseInt(document.getElementById('milliseconds').value, 10);
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("I work");
  }, millis);
});
```

```html
<button id="myElementId">Click me</button>
<input id="milliseconds" type="number" placeholder="number of milliseconds" />
```

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to explain the previous answer so that you understand where the problem is, and how to fix similar ones in the future, not only having it solved!*

### The Problem

JavaScript executes your code like this:

- The `clickbutton` variable stores your `button` element
- After that, the `millis` saves the **CURRENT** value of your input that equals `NaN`
- So, within your `setTimeout` function, you are passing the second argument as `NaN` that's why nothing happens, and the code runs instantly!

### How to fix it?

You need to put your `millis` variable inside the `addEventListener` function scope, so that whenever the user clicks on the button, JS go and get the value of your input *(At the time of clicking the button, not the time of launching the page!)*. Moreover, it changes the variable's value every time the button is clicked!

### Conclusion

Your problem isn't about dealing with `Scope` in JavaScript, it's all about the incorrect logic. **You are getting the input's value ONCE, not every time the user clicks on the button.**

Answer (score 0):

Get value after click like this

```js
    const clickbutton = document.getElementById('myElementId');

    clickbutton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // get value here after you click
        // this part run later wher you click
        const millis = parseInt(document.getElementById('milliseconds').value, 10);
        
        setTimeout(() => { alert("I work");
        }, millis);
    });
```